# How to read text lines in C

Tags: c, c99

I need to get lines from a text file. I already know that the lines won't be longer than 70 chars.
I have an idea about how to do it, but I'm looking a standard solution.

Comment: I've got 2 votes down. Please, explain why.

Comment: Most likely the downvotes are because Stack Overflow typically doesn't like you to post "Write my program for me" questions. "Here's what I have so far, here's what I need help with." makes a better question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
char line[MAXLEN];

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    /* Do something with line. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you're reading in a file you need to have a file pointer and indicate what you want to do with the file. i.e. r -> read, w-> write. So it looks like you want to read the file. 
So.....

```
Usage: gcc read.c -o read 
"read input.txt"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
FILE *fp;
char buffer[70];
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

while(fgets(buffer,70,fp) != NULL){
puts(buffer);
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

This takes in the file input.txt from the command line, puts it in the char buffer, prints it, and repeats until end of file.

Cheers